# Hacer una consulta enviando por medio de ajax el dato al controlador y obtener una respuesta

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo un pills tab de boostrap y cada enlace nav-link es un año, información que obtengo desde una consulta a la BD y completo el html con dicha información, necesito obtener la información del aria-controls ya que allí tengo solo el año sin otros caracteres, y al hacer clic obtener el año seleccionado, pero necesito enviar ese valor a un controlador laravel para hacer una consulta y devolver la colección a la vista.

En la vista tengo mi pill tab:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

@foreach($videos as $video)

<li class="nav-item" id="link-front">
  <a class="nav-link @if($loop->last) show active @endif"   id="{{ $video->year }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $video->year }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ $video->year }}" aria-selected="@if($loop->first) true @else false @endif">{{ $video->year }}</a>
</li>

@endforeach

</ul>
```

Este es el script de javascript:

```
<script>
  $("#myTab a").on('click', function (e) {
    var year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");
    console.log(year) // aquí debería obtener la información del año al hacer clic en el enlace.
 });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('index')}}",
    data: year, // aqui dice que la variable year no está definida.
    success: function(data) {
  }
});
</script>
```

Mi controlador:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    dd($year); // Aquí necesito la variable que contiene el año, enviado desde la vista.
}
```

Comment: el ajax debería estar dentro del evento click.. si no se ejecuta a la primera sin que este el year defindio

Comment: Gracias, con console.log veo que recibo el año pero no lo envía al controlador

Comment: Haz un `php artisan route:list` y comprueba el metodo y el nombre de la ruta

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en el directorio raíz "/" y tenía solamente la ruta GET, le agregué la ruta POST, voy a hacer pruebas y te aviso

Comment: Sigo sin recibirlo en el controlador

Comment: pon: `url: "/",`.... me temo que no estas cogiendo el nombre de la ruta... si es que le haz dado un nombre claro... me puedes decir el nombre de la ruta? en `php artisan route:list`

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que no estás recibiendo el dato en el controlador?¿por ese dd()? Si es así, no creo que te vayas a enterar si recibes o no el dato. Prueba poner `return $request->all();` en vez de `dd($year);` en el controlador, y en la llamada ajax haz un `console.log(data);` en la función success para ver que te responde. También sería útil que en el ajax hagas un catch además del success `error: function (error) { console.log(error); }`.

Comment: Okey, devuelve un JSON vacío []

Comment: ¿Y si en el data de ajax envías un objeto? `data: {year: year},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un snippet que hace una llamada a una [api de pruebas](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), que te devolverá el dato que le envías. Es sólo para comprobar que el javascript está funcionando. Puedes darle a ejecutar y verás que funciona correctamente.

```js
$("#myTab a").on('click', function (e) {
    let year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");
    console.log(year);
    
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: {
            year: year
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (error) { 
            console.log(error); 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

    <li class="nav-item" id="link-front">
    <a class="nav-link"   id="2019-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#2019" role="tab" aria-controls="2019">2019</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item" id="link-front">
    <a class="nav-link"   id="2020-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#2020" role="tab" aria-controls="2020">2020</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Entonces para tu código, puedes hacer lo mismo y debería funcionar.

En la **vista**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

@foreach($videos as $video)

  <li class="nav-item" id="link-front">
    <a class="nav-link @if($loop->last) show active @endif" id="{{ $video->year }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $video->year }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ $video->year }}" aria-selected="@if($loop->first) true @else false @endif">{{ $video->year }}</a>
  </li>

@endforeach

</ul>

<script>
    $("#myTab a").on('click', function (e) {
        let year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");

        let url = "{{route('index')}}"

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: {
                year: year
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (error) { 
                console.log(error); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Y en el **controlador**:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```